# What's wrong with my locked post?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, locked

I wrote [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784857/2784863#2784863) which had 2 upvotes last time I checked. Now it has 4 downvotes and it's been locked and deleted by the community. Why is that? I got around -200 reputation because of this and I don't know what's wrong with my post.

My Post:

> ```
> Not. You can't do that.
>
> if(4 <= $a <= 44) is equivalent to if((4 <= $a) <= 44) this may be
> ```
>
> if(false <= 44) or if(true <= 44) two
>   options is a bullshit.

EDIT: *Problem solved by the Bill The Lizard*. Thanks.

Comment: I'm reading below how you are using a translator, and it inserted the word...I'm sorry to hear that happened.  If you add a comment to your answer explaining what happened, I'm guessing it may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cleaned up the post, undeleted, and unlocked it.  Your choice of words may not be offensive in all parts of the world, but it is in many.  Just be careful what you say.

Update: Apparently the flags are still in the system, even though they don't show up on the dashboard.  I'm [looking in to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49121/community-user-will-delete-and-lock-a-post-twice) how to clear them.

2nd Update: After reading [@S.Mark's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49121/community-user-will-delete-and-lock-a-post-twice/49124#49124) on my other post, I undeleted the post without unlocking it and that seems to have appeased the Community process.  I'll go back and unlock it after the flags have had time to clear.

Comment: This is deleted along and i lost now -100 reputation for this.

Comment: now something more interesting happened, and I guess he got one more flag, and its got piled it up and another 100 rep taken from him and post locked again. I guess -100 is enough even if the word is really offensive.

Comment: @Svisstack: Sorry about that.  I'm definitely going to lobby to get those points back for you, since that was clearly my fault.  I'm also trying to figure out a way to undelete your post without costing you another 100 rep.

Comment: Thanks for Bill The Lizard for good report solution of repair the problem.

Answer (score 2):

"... two options is a bullshit."

Probably it got 6 flags as "offensive" and got deleted automatically.
Plus, you've lost 100 rep points, right?

Answer (score 0):

If the bullshit had been grammatical, I, for one, would not have flagged. The presence of 'bullshit' in apparent word salad pushed me over the edge for a flag.

Comment: @Svisstack: I understand how this happened. And I am not NickD.

Comment: I was quoting Svisstack.

Comment: @voy ok. got it.