# Community user will delete and lock a post twice

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderation

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784857/2784863#2784863) was flagged as offensive by the community, so it was deleted and locked.  The user who posted it [asked why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49114/whats-wrong-with-my-locked-post) here on meta.  I thought it was a simple matter of a bad translation, so I cleaned up the "bad word" and unlocked and undeleted the post.

The flags were apparently still in the system, because the Community user deleted and locked the post again, and unfortunately docked [Svisstack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283564/svisstack) another 100 points.  Can we (♦ moderators) get the ability to clear these flags *after* the penalties are applied, maybe through the post itself?  They don't show up in the dashboard (only posts with < 5 flags show up).

Also, can we get this poor guy his 100 points back?  That was my fault.

#### Update:

It looks like I just needed to use a combination of 10k tools and ♦ moderator tools to fix this.  Thanks a *lot* to [@S.Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213464/s-mark) for helping me figure this thing out.

Comment: It was not your fault, it was the system's

Comment: Couldn't you just fire up a recalc on him?

Comment: @devinb: I don't think that will refund his reputation.  The way things are going today, it might just *cost* him more.

Comment: you could flag me as offensive, and then try the recalc.
I've got rep to spare.

Comment: If it would help, I could say something offensive. I really hate minorities.

Comment: @devinb: That's a generous offer, but I'd need to be able to clear the flag before I could run any tests, and I still can't do that.

Comment: @Bill, looks like Marc Gravell aware this issue but Jonathan Sampson isn't, he unlocked that post. now its on the risk of another -100, its showing on the top of 10k tools [flagged](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) as 7 offensive flags.

Comment: @S.Mark: Very nice catch!  I caught it in time and cleared the flags before another -100 was applied.  Thank you!

Comment: Great @Bill, now looks fine, if he gets recalc, he will get his rep over 1000 back.

Comment: Perfect!, cheers @Bill :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/102311/revisions) one, looks like the work around is undelete it and let it remain locked, and wait 2 days to let all the flags gone, and unlocked. But still yes, for this case, <s>some dev need to touch db to restore his points back.</s> (moderators also can do, according to Bill's update)

Comment: +1 for being cleverer than a background process (and me, by transitivity).